# Install after VM clone

Tags: cardano-node

Hi guys I have installed 3 nodes (2 relays + one full) in Vbox VMs on a box at home, in order to start my stake pool. After a while I did a mistake and erased my cardano-src folder on one of them. I then cloned one of the ok ones into a new VM. Since i think i saw when installing that the scripts were generating keys or certificates, do you think my copied node will have problems when connecting to the other ones ? Thanks!

Comment: only one way to find out, try it :)